# Unable to import JSON file in R

Tags: r, json, dataframe

```
library(jsonlite)
post <- stream_in(file("posts.json"))
```

opening file input connection.

> Error: parse error: premature EOF
>                                          {
>                        (right here) ------^ closing file input connection.

I am getting this error.

Comment: Could you share the file with us?

Comment: Create a dummy one, you question isn't clear enough.

Comment: _"Post a client's sensitive data that I can't share on SO to a random online JSON validator."_ — really @SaurabhChauhan ?

Comment: There's a chance that there are embedded NULs causing a hiccup in the JSON processor. Try `ndjson::stream_in("posts.json")` and see if you get the same error (it has some line-by-line diagnostics that might spit out if there are file issues). It is also possible that the file is corrupt. You can perform _local_ validation outside of R with [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/).